# How to fill empty parts of a projected image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, projection

When i projected a 3D model on a 2D plan (Perspective projection) the result of the projection appeared as the following image.

[image: Resulted Projection]

and i need to fill empty points in this image to look like this one

i wonder that i can find a good way to fill this points with a professional way using any image processing algorithms using matlab

[image: Silhouette image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MATLAB version somewhat equivalent to [@belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599833/how-to-fill-empty-parts-of-a-projected-image/6600002#6600002) answer:

```
I = double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sedZH.png'));
BW = im2bw(I,graythresh(I));
BW = imerode(BW,strel('square',2*3+1));
BW = imfilter(BW, fspecial('average',10));
BW = imdilate(BW,strel('square',2*3+1));
BW = imcomplement(BW);
imshow(BW)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Amr Ramdan :: Currently, I am working on the same problem. Can you see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372739/perspective-projection-of-a-3d-head-to-form-a-face-image> and comment... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Code in [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). Matlab surely has the equivalent image transformations.

[image]

Let's see how both images fit:

[image]

As you can see, the neck is a bit Hulkish ... otherwise the result is quite good

Comment: @Amr I don't have Matlab at hand, but I know these basic commands have a one-to-one correspondence in Matlab

Comment: i do it with some way in matlab that i created a square ant fill it but it gives me a very very poor result (http://i.imgur.com/0UGiy.png)

Comment: @Amr The purpose of the `Blur` followed by the `Sharpen` is to get rid of those ugly borders

Comment: i think it's  a wonderful result for me but i tried to do this using matlab :S but it didn't help me :( after using sharpen first and then blur 
actually i didn't know what should i do after doing sharpening

Comment: @Amr The sequence is 1-> Binarize, 2-> Erode, 3-> Blur, 4-> Sharpen, 5 -> Binarize, 6 -> Dilate, 7 -> Negate Color