# Perspective Projection and Z-buffering of a 3D head to form a face image

Tags: c++, matlab, 3d, projection, perspectivecamera

**Input:** 53490 3D points and for each point (xyz) and color (rgb) of a head

**Output:** 2D face image as viewed from a particular position / direction

**Platform:** Matlab  C/C++

After study, I found the **steps** to be implemented

- Perspective Projection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection
- Z-buffering http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering
- Phong reflection model http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model

I implemented the above 3 steps in Matlab. But it takes 8 min for the execution. The 2D rendering is part of my project; I will be calling the 2D rendering part 5000 times later. I want the execution time under 1sec.

The bulk (99.9%) of time is taking for z-buffering. The implementation is done following the wiki link.
Can anyone help me to reduce the time in Matlab or suggest other platform?
Any tutorials/demo references to understand the above steps will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I followed the steps in the wiki links mentioned in the question.. For z-buffering; it takes 8 min for my program... Can you suggest on how to optimize the z-buffering part.. And overall any suggestions and references will be helpful... Once the computation time comes down, I want to concentrate on the quality part...

Comment: What kind of data are you data? Is it volume data? I mean are they points only on the surface or they are points from the whole volume of the head? (for example from a medical scan). Also, to implement the Phong model you must have surface information, you have that too?

Comment: The 3D data of head is in ply format. @Phong model:: I am using some default values for the coefficients.

Comment: can't you use OpenGL in your project? it would be much faster and also wouldn't be that hard to implement.

Comment: @2vision2: it looks like you are describing the usual [graphics pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline). In C why dont you use OpenGL as suggested. In MATLAB you dont have to worry about any of this, just plot the points and use the rotate button to change the view...

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions...I will start using OpenGL as suggested.. I previously worked with Matlab; that is why I chose Matlab... 
@Amro :: The 2D projection is not for visualization, I want to use the projected 2D image to compare with a ground truth image. The projection is part of a 3D reconstruction project I am working on. I am implementing 3D Morphable Models for the reconstruction.

Comment: @2vision2: oh, it wasn't clear from the description.. How about doing [off-screen rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) into a buffer, would that apply in your case?

Comment: @Amro :: I started using OpenGL today (6hrs ago) only. I will look into what you said, I think FBO should suit my problem. Can you comment on OpenGL vs VTK.. Thank you for your response!!!

Comment: @2vision2: im afraid i never used VTK..

Comment: @Amro :: Can you point me to any code which has the entire 3D Graphics Rendering Pipeline in it. I am following <http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/CG_BasicsTheory.html> and currently coding that tutorial.

Comment: @2vision2: sorry, i dont have anything specific. I suppose there are many resources online on the subject... In MATLAB, I have seen this [one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26567-3d-graphics-pipeline) before, but never took a close look. Good luck to you on your project

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you doing this in matlab, because you may need to visualize a big volume.
Try vtk, and you may need some programming.

Here is a simple one (3D project) from ImageJ: http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=gui:image:stacks